# Making logarithmic function go higher

Tags: functions, logarithms

I am looking at logarithmic functions, and, lets say, `log2 (x+3)` is having a bit of a growth rate between `0-10` values of `x`, but then it has almost no growth rate.

I need some function that looks similar to a linear function, but is slightly bent like a logarithm function is.

How do I modify my logarith function?

**Edit**: I made something like this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+log_100%28x%5E128%29++from+x%3D2+to+x%3D4000 and I have almost the results I want, but I would like this function to not go as extreme high in first `0-500` values of `x` axis.

Comment: You are aware that $\log x^{128} = 128\log x$, so the function you've linked is just some scaled version of $\log x$?

Comment: @martini: Wasn't aware, of that, thanks. ;) But I need to modify it somehow so it will get "wider" at the beginning, and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modification: $$a-a^{1-\frac{x}{b}}.$$

This starts at the origin, and quickly converges to $a$. After a point there is relatively speaking little growth. Try making $a=10$, and $b=5$, and then setting your aspect ratio to 1 in a better grapher (for example [ojek graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0onfu6xbqj) allows manipulate constructions).

Comment: Ouch. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%E2%88%92e%5E%281%E2%88%92%E2%88%9Ax%29 did I input it right? I am looking for something that will look more or less like a north-west quarter of a circle that starts in 0,0

Comment: @ojek See my modification. I made a manipulator with square aspect ratio in [ojek graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0onfu6xbqj)

Comment: Thank you, that helped. :)